# erlide edoc generator

Tags: documentation, erlang, erlide

Does anyone know how to add automatic edoc to function in ErlIde?

In java eclipse understands and and add some java doc when I put /* before function name is there similar functionality for ErlIde?

Thanks in advance

`%%%===================================================================`
`%% @spec ${function_name}(${function_parameters})->${function_result}`
`%%`
`%% where`
`%% ${function_parameters}`
`%%`
`%% @doc`
`%%`
`%% @end`
`%%%===================================================================`
Something this kind would be nice I guess

Ps:(Sorry I was not able to make this formating in the comment I am quite new)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have this functionality yet. What default content would you expect in the generated edoc?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see [on the Erlide home page](http://erlide.sourceforge.net/erlide.html) an EDoc viewer is included but no automatic generation seems to be supported.